# Carto does not find several Swiss administrative regions?

Tags: carto, switzerland

I'm trying to highlight all different cantons of Switzerland and then give them a different color. However Carto does not find several administrative regions and there seems to be no way to change this.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo error. The geocoder fails when the kanton name is not among a list of administrative regions alternative names.

CARTO provinces geocoder (`admin1`) uses Natural Earth Data, as explained [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/data-services/tree/master/geocoder/admin1). You can download a table with the right names and geometries from [here](https://team.carto.com/u/ramirocartodb/tables/switzerland_admin1/public). Also, have a look at this [map](https://ramirocartodb.carto.com/builder/02390d48-d19c-11e6-af17-0ecd1babdde5/embed), it is built using the whole `admin1` table in case you need any further data:

[image]